# Scala: Abstracting the toString function of case classes

Tags: scala, inheritance, typeclass, shapeless, case-class

Suppose I have a case class defined as follows:

```
case class User(name: String, age: Int)
```

I would like to override its `toString` method like this:

```
 case class User(name: String, age: Int) {
    override def toString: String = 
      s"name = $name
        age = $age"
```

So that if I run `print(user.toString)`, I get:

```
name = nameOfUser
age = ageOfUser
```

Now I have another class called `Computer` and it is defined as

```
case class Computer(make: String, RAM: int, clockSpeed: Double)
```

I would like to print the same for all its values. I would like something like:

```
  make = makeOfComputer
  RAM = RAMOfComputer
  clockSpeed = speedOfComputer
```

Instead of copying, pasting and adapting the above `toString` function to the `Computer` class, I'd rather abstract this away so that it can be used by any case class.

Some ideas I have are that I can use

```
 CaseClassType.unapply(caseClassInstance).get.productIterator.toList
```

to get the values of the case class and

```
 classOf[CaseClass].getDeclaredFields.map(_.getName)
```

to get the names of the fields. What this means is that I can find a list of all the values in a case class as well as a list of all the field names without knowing the actual structure of the case class at all.

Once I have these two collections, I can recursively go through them to create the string. I was thinking something like the below could work but unfortunately scala doesn't allow case classes to inherit from other case classes.

```
case class StringifiableCaseClass(){
  override def toString: String =
     //get the values and the fieldnames and create a string
```

All I'd have to do is get the case classes to extend `StringifiableCaseClass` and they would be able to create the right string.

The reason why I want to use a case class as the base type is that I can use

```
 classOf[this.type]...etc
```

and

```
  this.type.unapply(this)...etc
```

in `StringifiableCaseClass`.

Any ideas on how I can achieve what I am after given I cannot extend case classes with other case classes?

Comment: Is using something like Shapeless acceptable for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The base implementation does not have to be a case class. Just make it a trait, and then your case classes can all extend it.

```
 trait Stringification { self: Product => 
    override def toString() = 
      getClass.getDeclaredFields
      .zip(productIterator.toSeq)
      .map { case (a, b) => s"${a.getName}=$b" }
      .mkString("\n")
 }
```

and then

```
  case class Foo(foo: String, bar: Int) extends Stringification
  case class Bar(foo: Foo, bar: String) extends Stringification
```

... etc.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your use-case correctly, you can use Cats default `Show` type-class or, if you need more custom behaviour, you can directly use generic derivation with `Shapeless` to achieve what you are after.

For the easier scenario of Cat's `Show`, read [here](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/show.html).

As you can read, it has syntax that will let you do `myObject.show` on any `T` that has a `Show[T]` in scope.

If you want a more customisable behaviour, you can try going directly with Shapeless. An example of what you need can be found in [this example `Show` type-class](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/shows.scala) and you can see it running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/emmedema/dxKmeqjgReyL1rPGO1C1Pw).

Given these case classes:

```
  sealed trait Super
  case class Foo(i: Int, s: String) extends Super
  case class Bar(i: Int) extends Super
  case class BarRec(i: Int, rec: Super) extends Super

  sealed trait MutualA
  case class MutualA1(x: Int) extends MutualA
  case class MutualA2(b: MutualB) extends MutualA

  sealed trait MutualB
  case class MutualB1(x: Int) extends MutualB
  case class MutualB2(b: MutualA) extends MutualB
```

It will print:

```
Bar(i = 0)   
BarRec(i = 1, rec = Foo(i = 0, s = foo))   
MutualA2(b = MutualB2(b = MutualA1(x = 0)))
```